# Unable to implement a logic in ajax with Cakephp2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

I have a website made by CakePHP2 and I want to implement a function with Ajax that will transition to the other URL if a certain condition in the PHP is met, else will show an error dialog. I find many tutorials on the Google difficult to understand. It will be great if you can give me some tips or examples.

[Example logic]

> $data['payment'] is the value passed from the controller to the view.

(1. If an order button is clicked the Ajax method will be called.

(2. If the $data['payment'] is true. Will transition to the other directory.

(3. If the $data['payment'] is false. Will show an alert dialog and disable the order button so that the user won't be able to click.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: It is Cakephp2.0

Comment: Could you explain the second condition? I Did not get this part 'Will transition to the other directory.'.

Answer (score 0):

I Did not get your second condition. Could you give more details?

```
if ( !$data['payment'] ) {

    echo $this->Form->button('Button', ['disabled' => 'disabled']);

    $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false));
        echo $this->Js->alert('Your message error');
    $this->Html->scriptEnd();

} else {
    echo $this->Form->button('Button', ['onClick' => 'ajaxMethod()']);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my explanation is not good.  For example,  there is a button that the user can press that will transition to another page. However, the condition to transition to that page is if the user had already paid ($data['payment'] is true). If the user has not paid, an error message will tell the user to pay and the button it's self will be disabled.

Comment: So I think my answer is enough, the redirect will be done by ajax or a link?